# Using a path dependant type in a superclass signature

Tags: scala, types

Given the following scala code:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException
import spray.json.{JsString, JsValue, JsonFormat, deserializationError}

class EnumJsonFormat[EnumType <: Enumeration](val enum: EnumType) {
  val format: JsonFormat[enum.Value] = new JsonFormat[enum.Value] {
    override def write(obj: enum.Value): JsValue = ???
    override def read(json: JsValue): enum.Value = ???
  }
}

class EnumJsFormat[EnumType <: Enumeration](val enum: EnumType) extends JsonFormat[enum.Value] {
  override def write(obj: enum.Value): JsValue = ???
  override def read(json: JsValue): enum.Value = ???
}
```

The first version compiles, and provides the enum (de-)serializer I need. The second one fails with the compiler reporting `not found: value enum`

Unfortunately this saddles me with the inelegant need to reference the `format` field (`new EnumJsonFormat(MyEnum).format` instead of just `new EnumJsFormat(MyEnum)`)  in addition to a unnecessary "outer object" reference.

Is there a way to use the path-dependant type inside the superclass signature, or any other idiom to "mask" the inner field?

Comment: Not sure what's the reason. Your workaround seems needed, or something like `trait Foo[A] { def foo(v: A): Unit }; def Bar[EnumType <: Enumeration](enum: EnumType): Foo[enum.Value] = new Foo[enum.Value] { def foo(v: enum.Value) = ??? }`

Comment: Maybe relevant https://github.com/buildo/ingredients/tree/master/caseenum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you cannot use a dependent type as a type constructor parameter of the super-type, you could only use it as a type of a constructor argument.

You can work around this by introducing another type constructor parameter:

```
trait JsValue

trait JsonFormat[A] {
  def write(obj: A): JsValue
  def read(json: JsValue): A
}

class EnumJsFormat[V,EnumType <: Enumeration](val enum: EnumType {type Value = V}) 
  extends JsonFormat[V] {

  def write(obj: V): JsValue = ???
  def read(json: JsValue): V = ???
}
```

Alternatively,

```
EnumJsFormat[V, EnumType <: Enumeration { type Value = V }](val enum: EnumType)
```